# Cannot resolve method 'format (java.lang.string,java.Util.Date)'

Tags: android

I get this error:

[image: problem screenshot]

I am new in android App development. Can any one help me?

Comment: check my answer. Hopefully it will be solved.

Comment: Please don't post your code as screenshots.

Comment: ok...........................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to call the the method through object. It is not a static method.

```
android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
dateTextView.setText(df.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", date).toString());
```

Comment: thankyou....

now it's not showing error

Comment: Thanks, it works for me !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the imports:

```
import java.util.Date;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
```

If this fails you may miss some library files or have your Android SDK setup messed up. Maybe you should put more information and be more specific to avoid getting more downvotes.

Greetings!

Comment: he has to call the the method through object. It is not a static method.